# Cannot catch signal_motion_notify_event in gtkmm

Tags: events, gtk, gtkmm, notify, motion

I used following code to catch motion notify events on a Gtk::TreeView.

```
// This is the Gtk::Builder from which i read my tree view.
builder_ptr->get_widget("treeview", m_treeview_ptr);

// Connecting that event.
m_treeview_ptr->add_events(Gdk::POINTER_MOTION_MASK |
                           Gdk::POINTER_MOTION_HINT_MASK);
m_treeview_ptr->signal_motion_notify_event().connect(
    sigc::mem_fun(this, &LayoutEditorDialog::_on_motion_notify));
```

My slot function looks like this:

```
bool LayoutEditorDialog::_on_motion_notify(GdkEventMotion* event) const
{
    // Just a test.
    std::cout << event->x << " " << event->y << std::endl;
}
```

Somhow no motion notify events will be sent from the tree view. Can someone help me here?
Thanks!

Comment: You might try taking off the HINT_MASK since that requires you to explicitly request more motion events.  I'd expect you to get at least one though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to use connect_notify instead of notify, because my signal is from a event.